# Link to external object in Google MyMaps

Tags: google

I have got a map created in Google MyMaps, which contain a lot of points:

https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=1yyHAfiqoMCB2X3oswH2HKemh304&ll=-2.3807679248749665%2C0&z=2

Is it possible to input a link to every single point in the description, when click "Edit" option?

AN only option, which I can see there is the photo. I would like to have also a link to particular URL from that place.

I was trying to input some HTML stuff such this:

a href="https://www.britannica.com/science/rift-valley"Spectacular Great Rift Valley> but it doesn't work. It looks like is not supported by Google.

An only option is pick up the point at arleady existing location provided by Google Maps, which arleady has some link.

Is the Google MyMaps tool support a link option at all?

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been resolved. 
Google MyMaps doesn't support an external link, however you can manage with it, making the hyperlink in another interactive map builder, like Scribble Maps and then export it (via .kml file) to Google MyMaps.
An another solution is change the XML (.kml) file code.
Remember, that GoogleMyMaps treats the .kml file as a every single layer (this tool enable you to input 8 layers only), so better is when you set the link attributes for all placemark needed.

More details about it you can find in the article below:

http://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/link-management-in-google-mymaps-and-kml-files/