# How to add a webpage link to google map marker description

Tags: google-maps, google

I have multiple pin points on my google maps, with a small description. 
I want to add a link page (on my computer) to the description and make it linkable. Whenever I clicked, a new tab opens? Is it possible?
I tried this on google map marker

```
<a href='ma_path_on_my_computer/description.html'>description</a>
```

but it just displays it as a text.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: but i added all things (whats i look for and what i tried ) isnt it? , thanks

Comment: how are you adding the link to your description? what is the whole of the text in the description?

Comment: using html tags <a href='path/desc.html' target='_blank'></a> , the whole text (go to this web page) its all

Comment: You should post your code snippet where you include the InfoWindow and its content, otherwise it'll be almost impossible to help you.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315195/link-to-external-object-in-google-mymaps#318457 and the answer is google doesn't support that directly.